# Excel vba Compile error - Argument not optional,

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure this out and can't.

I keep getting an error: "Compile error - Argument not optional". I am supplying the arguments and they are set as Optional!

Trying to pass a string and an array to a function and count occurrences of the array strings within the string passed.

Code stops running at the line:

```
Public Function countTextInText(Optional text As String, Optional toCountARR As Variant) As Integer
```

with a "Compile error: Argument not optional" message highlighting the `Val` in the line:

```
    For Each Val In toCountARR
```

Full code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nameR As Range
    Dim colR As Range

    Dim TKRcnt As Integer
    Dim TKRarr() As Variant
    TKRarr = Array("TKR", "THR", "Bipolar")

    Dim ORIFcnt As Integer
    Dim ORIFarr() As Variant
    TKRarr = Array("ORIF", "Ilizarov", "PFN")


    Set nameR = Range("P2:P9")
    Set colR = Range("B2:B50,G2:G50,L2:L50")

    For Each namecell In nameR
        For Each entrycell In colR
            If entrycell.text = namecell.text Then
                TKRcnt = countTextInText(entrycell.Offset(0, 2).text, TKRarr)
                ORIFcnt = countTextInText(entrycell.Offset(0, 2).text, TKRarr)
            End If
        Next entrycell

        MsgBox (namecell.text & " TKR count: " & TKRcnt & " ORIF count: " & ORIFcnt)

    Next namecell
End Sub

Public Function countTextInText(Optional text As String, Optional toCountARR As Variant) As Integer
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim inStrLoc As Integer

    For Each Val In toCountARR
        inStrLoc = InStr(1, text, Val)
        While inStrLoc <> 0
            inStrLoc = InStr(inStrLoc, text, Val)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        Wend
    Next Val

    Set countTextInText = cnt
End Function
```

Comment: (a) which line is giving the "Argument not optional" error?  (b) You can't `Set countTextInText = cnt`, it should be `Let countTextInText = cnt`, which would normally be written as just `countTextInText = cnt`.

Comment: Error line is:
`Public Function countTextInText(Optional text As String, Optional toCountARR As Variant) As Integer`

Comment: Ignore my previous (a) comment, I see you get a compile error on `Val`.  `Val` is an Excel function that requires a mandatory argument to be passed to it.  If you wish to use that as a variable name, you will need to declare it as a variable.  But it is a better idea to choose a more appropriate variable name.  (But declaring your variables is a very good idea anyway!)

Comment: I think you need a default value for optional arguments, if I remember correctly. What value do you expect when the argument is not supplied?

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks mate, this helped me solved that annoying issue! how do I rate / vote for your reply? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Val` is a VBA function which requires a single, **mandatory**, argument - therefore the compiler generates the message saying "Argument not optional" if you don't provide that argument.  ([MSDN documentation of `Val`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/val-function))

It is a bad idea to use VBA function names as variable names, so I would recommend you don't use `Val` as a variable name - use `myVal` or anything else that VBA hasn't already used.

If you **really** want to use `Val` (and you are sure that you won't be needing to access the `Val` function at all), you can use it as a variable name if you simply declare it as such, e.g.

```
Dim Val As Variant
```

---

You will also have problems with your line saying

```
Set countTextInText = cnt
```

as `countTextInText` has been declared to be an `Integer`, and `Set` should only be used when setting a variable to be a reference to an object.  So that line should be

```
countTextInText = cnt
```

Comment: Nice! For me the problem was I forgot `Set` on a `ByRef` parameter, it was confusing though because it was the first line of the Sub so the error message threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming late to this question because of the question's title, as I did, having received this error while using the .Find method -

In my case, the problem was that the variable I was `Set`ing was not `Dim`d at top of function.

#### My Example

```
Sub MyTest()
    Dim tst, rngAll
    rngAll = [a1].CurrentRegion
    tst = fnFix1Plus1InValues(ByVal rngAll As Range)
End Sub

Public Function fnFix1Plus1InValues(ByVal rngAll As Range) As Boolean
    Dim t1, t2, arr, Loc '<=== Needed Loc added here
    Set Loc = rngAll.Find(What:="+", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
        Do Until Loc Is Nothing
            t1 = Loc.Value
            If fnContains(t1, "+") Then
                'Do my stuff
            End If
            Set Loc = rngAll.FindNext(Loc)
        Loop
    End If
End Function 'fnFix1Plus1InValues
```